# WPF Style issue in WPF Datagrid

Tags: wpf, datagrid, wpfdatagrid, styling

I have a WPF datagrid and i have bound it with an observablecollection. It is working fine but the issue is that I have apply the styles at cell level at runtime. There is a sample method ApplyStyleAtCellLevelInDataGrid() which is mentioned below. I have to call this method two times to show the effect of styles in WPF DataGrid. Why is it so...

Here is XAML

```
 <Style x:Key="BaseStyle"  TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
     <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
     <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>        
     <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="10"/>
     <Setter Property="TextAlignment" Value="Center"/>
 </Style>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}" x:Key="Col1Style" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseStyle}">

        <Setter Property="Background">
            <Setter.Value>
                <SolidColorBrush Color="Tomato"/>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>            

        <Style.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Binding.TargetUpdated">
                <BeginStoryboard HandoffBehavior="Compose">
                    <Storyboard TargetProperty="(TextBlock.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                    <ColorAnimation Duration="0:0:1.5" To="DarkRed"  AutoReverse="True" RepeatBehavior="1" />
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

< Style x:Key="DGCellStyle" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">

```
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="10"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"></Setter>           
    </Style>
```

Grid Declaration in XAML

```
<DataGrid Name="dataGrid1"  ItemsSource="{Binding Values}" CellStyle="{StaticResource DGCellStyle}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" UseLayoutRounding="False">

  <DataGrid.Columns>
      <DataGridTextColumn  Header="Value" Binding="{Binding Value1, Mode=OneWay, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}" Width="0.25*"/>
      <DataGridTextColumn Header="Value 1" Binding="{Binding Value2, Mode=OneWay, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}" Width="0.25*"/>
      <DataGridTextColumn Header="Value 2" Binding="{Binding Value3, Mode=OneWay, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}" Width="0.25*"/>
      <DataGridTextColumn Header="Value 3" Binding="{Binding Value4, Mode=OneWay, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}" Width="0.25*"/>
   </DataGrid.Columns>           
 </DataGrid>
```

Code

```
 private void ApplyStyleAtCellLevelInDataGrid()

    {
        if (Values == null || Values.Count == 0)
        {
            Values = new ObservableCollection<MyClass>();
            Values.Add(new MyClass { Value1 = "1", Value4 = "2", Value2 = "4", Value3 = "3" });
            Values.Add(new MyClass { Value1 = "2", Value4 = "3", Value2 = "5", Value3 = "7" });
            Values.Add(new MyClass { Value1 = "3", Value4 = "4", Value2 = "7", Value3 = "2" });
            Values.Add(new MyClass { Value1 = "4", Value4 = "4", Value2 = "8", Value3 = "6" });
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (var item in Values)
            {
                MyClass c = item as MyClass;
                c.Value1 = _rand.Next(0, 100).ToString();         
                c.Value2 = _rand.Next(0, 100).ToString();
                c.Value3 = _rand.Next(0, 100).ToString();
                c.Value4 = _rand.Next(0, 100).ToString();
            }
        }

        //////////////

        DataGridCell cell = GetCell(1, 1);

        Style defaultStyle = (Style)FindResource("NewStyle");
        ((TextBlock)cell.Content).Style = defaultStyle;

        cell = GetCell(1, 2);
        defaultStyle = (Style)FindResource("NewStyleExtended");
        ((TextBlock)cell.Content).Style = defaultStyle;

        cell = GetCell(2, 2);
        defaultStyle = (Style)FindResource("NewStyle");
        ((TextBlock)cell.Content).Style = defaultStyle;

        cell = GetCell(2, 3);
        defaultStyle = (Style)FindResource("Col1Style");
        ((TextBlock)cell.Content).Style = defaultStyle;
    }


 private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {         
// Single call of this method does not work,

I have to call two times then it shows the effect

        ApplyStyleAtCellLevelInDataGrid(); 
        ApplyStyleAtCellLevelInDataGrid();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your Style's `TargetType` from a `TextBlock` to a `DataGridCell`, then apply the style as the `DataGrid.CellStyle`. Since you already have a `CellStyle` set to `DGCellStyle`, you'll probably have to merge the two styles.

Also, you'll need to change `TextAlignment` to `HorizontalAlignment` in your base style since `TextAlignment` is not a property of `DataGridCell`

```
<Style x:Key="BaseStyle"  TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
     <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
     <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>        
     <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="10"/>
     <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
 </Style>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}" x:Key="Col1Style" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseStyle}">
    <Setter Property="Background">
        <Setter.Value>
            <SolidColorBrush Color="Tomato"/>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>            

    <Style.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Binding.TargetUpdated">
            <BeginStoryboard HandoffBehavior="Compose">
                <Storyboard TargetProperty="(DataGridCell.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                <ColorAnimation Duration="0:0:1.5" To="DarkRed"  AutoReverse="True" RepeatBehavior="1" />
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

And

```
<DataGrid CellStyle="{StaticResource Col1Style}" ... />
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but my mail question is that why have I to call ApplyStyleAtCellLevelInDataGrid(); 2 times in Window_Loaded event to show the effect of style? Calling it once does not show anything on screen

Comment: @AsadNaeem My best guess is that it has something to do with WPF's [DispatcherPriority](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcherpriority.aspx), and that the first run through is creating the `Values` collection that your `Grid` is bound to, and either the DataGrid items haven't finished rendering, or the default style gets applied during the render pass and overwriting your custom style, so that's why a 2nd run through is needed. I won't know for sure without setting up a test scenario though.

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in implementing a DataTemplateSelector. This object is used to provide  the display logic on any data item.

Here's a quick tutorial: http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/wpf-tutorial-how-to-use-a-datatemplateselector

Comment: Thanks for the answer but my mail question is that why have I to call ApplyStyleAtCellLevelInDataGrid(); in Window_Loaded event to show the effect of style? Calling it once does not show anything on screen

Comment: I don't know. But there are interfaces in WPF that are meant to modify a style based on custom logic and you aren't using them. My answer is: Perhaps if you used the tools at your disposals instead of going around it, you wouldn't even need your "ApplystyleAtCellLevel" function.

Answer (score 0):

In App.xaml add

`"xmlns:dg="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wpf/2008/toolkit"` in Application tag.

In `<Application.Resources>` tag add

```
<Style x:Key="ColumnHeaderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type dg:DataGridColumnHeader}">
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
</Style>

<Style x:Key="CellRightAlign" TargetType="{x:Type dg:DataGridCell}">
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Right" />
</Style>
```

Now in code behind of add `AutoGeneratedColumns` event to your datagrid

```
Style RightAlign = (Style)FindResource("CellRightAlign");
yourGrid.Columns[0].CellStyle = RightAlign;
```